# How to get comments and replies?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to make a comments and replies to comments for media posted by users. 
My comments table is structured like:

```
commentId : parentCommentId : mediaId : userId : comment
```

I want to select the most recent 10 original comments and their replies to a mediaId.

To do this I am running 2 sql statements.

```sql
SELECT commentId FROM comments
WHERE mediaId='3' AND parentCommentId='0'
LIMIT 10;
```

(This gets the commentIds of the most recent original 10 posts.
I then use these commentIds in the following)...

```sql
SELECT c.*,u.* FROM comments AS c
JOIN users AS u on u.userId=c.userId 
WHERE parentCommentId IN --( *****commentIds from previous query***** );
```

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaphs using a `JOIN`?

Answer (score 1):

What if you make it this way:

```
    SELECT c.*,u.* FROM comments c
    JOIN users u on u.userId=c.userId 
    JOIN comments p_c on p_c.commentId = c.parentCommentId
    WHERE p_c.mediaId='3' AND p_c.parentCommentId='0'
    LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Don't wrap integers into quotes when the field is type `int` this will cause casting on each row in the table which slows down even simple queries

Comment: @MichelFeldheim, I know about that - it's a copy-paste from OP's sql - we don't really know if these fields are integer =)

Comment: k102 thanks for your answer... I will give it a go and then come back later to mark as answer... I assume your way is the most efficient way to do it?... also thanks @MichelFeldheim for the advise... regards J

Comment: i think `p_c.commentId  = c.parentCommentId` is wrong because parentCommentId will always be '0'.

Comment: @RanjitSingh, um... why? The condition is `p_c.parentCommentId='0'` (`p_c`, not `c`)

Comment: Hey @k102... I have tested this out however it is only selecting the child rows and not the rows where parentCommentId=0 ... thanks for your continued support.. regards J

Comment: @jon, I think you can add `p_c.*` to the query - but you have to rename fields since the tables are the same

Answer (score 0):

This will be useful for your problem

```
    SELECT c.*,u.* FROM comments AS c
    INNER JOIN users AS u on u.userId=c.userId 
    INNER JOIN comments pc on pc.commentId = c.CommentId
    WHERE pc.mediaId='3' AND pc.parentCommentId='0'
    LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: thanks for the response however this way does not work as it is only selecting rows where parentCommentId='0'... I need it to select the 10 most recent with parentComentId=0 and their children (replies)... that said k102's answer is also not working.. see other thread.. thanks again for your support.